# Is DAO the Route To Go For Query Creation

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, dao

This seems a bit robust to me (and takes some time to complete) is there a faster way to use `C#` to create an Access Query?  This is the code I  have been using:

```
DAO.Database dd;
DAO.DBEngine db = new DAO.DBEngine();
var qd8 = new DAO.QueryDef();
String queryName = String.Format("SELECT Count(*) from table14");
string path = @"E:\\Databases\\database123.mdb";
dd = db.OpenDatabase(path);
qd8.Name = String.Format("Total_Count");
qd8.SQL = String.Format(queryName);
dd.QueryDefs.Append(qd8);
```

Comment: You could execute the same SQL query using `System.Data.Odbc` or `System.Data.OleDb` (and not save the query to the QueryDefs collection if you don't expect to use it again). Have you tried either of those alternatives?

Comment: What is your reason to create these queries? Are you just trying to execute the queries, or are you trying to add the queries to the .mdb files?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I am wanting to create and save the queries in the access database.   Trying to add the queries to the .mdb files.

Comment: @GordThompson - I need to save the querydef as I will use again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "faster" mean to you?

I ran this on my test database:

```
DAO.DBEngine de = new DAO.DBEngine();
DAO.Database dd;
DAO.QueryDef qd8 = new DAO.QueryDef();
string path = @"c:\test\testdb.mdb";
string queryName = @"TotalCountX";
string querySql = @"Select Count(*) From TableOne";

dd = de.OpenDatabase(path);
qd8.Name = queryName;
qd8.SQL = querySql;
dd.QueryDefs.Append(qd8);
```

Execution time was 85 ms.

Adding two queries:

```
DAO.DBEngine de = new DAO.DBEngine();
DAO.Database dd;
DAO.QueryDef qd8 = new DAO.QueryDef();
string path = @"c:\test\testdb.mdb";
string queryName = @"TotalCountY";
string querySql = @"Select Count(*) From TableOne";

dd = de.OpenDatabase(path);
qd8.Name = queryName;
qd8.SQL = querySql;
dd.QueryDefs.Append(qd8);

qd8 = new DAO.QueryDef();
queryName = @"TotalCountZ";
querySql = @"Select Count(*) From TableTwo";
qd8.Name = queryName;
qd8.SQL = querySql;
dd.QueryDefs.Append(qd8);
```

executed in 89 ms, so adding one query is about 4 ms.

What is your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You could execute this [CREATE VIEW Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177895%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```sql
CREATE VIEW Total_Count AS SELECT Count(*) FROM table14
```

If you attempt to execute it from DAO, Access will throw a syntax error.  So execute it from an OleDb connection instead.

However, I'm uncertain whether this approach will be noticeably faster than your current code.